# How to Solve for $x$ in a Particular Exponential Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, exponentiation

I am trying to solve for $x$ in

$x^2=(16)^{2x}.$

So I started this way:
I took square root of both sides and got

$x=16^x$

Then I took the logarithm of both sides and got
$\log x=x \log 16.$

This is where I got stuck.

Comment: $x^2 = 4$ does not imply $x = 2$ - taking the positive square root of both sides is not a valid rearrangement

Comment: Thought the square root cancels the 2 by the X

Comment: It's 16^(2x). So the 1/2 cancels the 2

Comment: It can be solved with the help of the LambertW function.

Comment: I already provided a counterexample - you need a $\pm$

Comment: Pls explain more. I don't get it

Comment: I'll leave someone else to explain the Lambert W function approach, I'm not familiar with it. But if $x^2 = 9$, say, note that $x = \pm 3$. So it's not valid just to take the square root of both sides without thinking - you may miss out on a solution.

Comment: Ok, but then i need to solve this in an easy amd simpler way

Comment: @AshalleySamuel: there is no simple way, look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @bounceback The first operation is valid since both sides must be positive, since RHS is positive.

Comment: @bounceback If $x$ is a real number $x^2$ will always be positive.  One can avoid "missing solutions" by remembering $\sqrt{(x^2)}=|x|$.  So your first step above will get you to $|x|=16^x$.  If you graph both sides of this equation you can see that $x \approx -0.3642$  (see https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xpbfejetjp

Comment: Interesting. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^{2} = 16^{2x} = (16^{x})^{2}$, and so,

$x^{2} - (16^{x})^{2} = (x + 16^{x})(x-16^{x}) = 0.$

Now, setting $y_{1} = x + 16^{x}$ and $y_{2}=x-16^{2}$, and then graphing both equations, it will be seen that $y_{2}$ does not cross the $x$-axis (and so admits no solution to this problems), whereas $y_{1}$ crosses the $x$-axis exactly once in the interval $(-1, 0)$.

Thus, we may apply, for example, Newton's method to $y_{1} = x + 16^{x}$ to approximate the unique solution to the given exponential equation, which as somebody has already pointed out, is on the order of $-.36435$.

Comment: Ohk. That's very understandable. Will try this one. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to some other answers,

$$x=-0.36424988978364795656$$ is the real solution. (Can be expressed in terms of the Lambert $W$ function; otherwise there is no analytical expression.)

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%3D256%5Ex

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated in your question, the first step is to take both sides into a square root (knowing that $x > 0$, no roots will be lost doing this) and then to take the natural log of both sides:

$$ \sqrt {x^2} = \sqrt {16^{2x}}$$
$$ x = 16^x $$
$$ \ln x = x \ln 16 $$
$$ \frac {\ln x}{\ln 16} = x $$

Now, we know that $x$ cannot be between 0 and 1, as $-\infty < \frac {\ln x}{\ln 16} < 0$ and $0 < x < 1$. So, $x > 1$.

After this point, we will use some calculus to figure out if the lines $y=x$ and $y=\frac {\ln x}{\ln 16}$ even intersect. If we know that when $x=1$, $\frac {\ln x}{\ln 16} = 0$, we can prove that they do not intersect by finding both of their derivatives.

$$ \frac {d} {dx} [x] = 1$$
$$ \frac {d} {dx} [\frac {\ln x}{\ln 16}] = \frac {1}{x\ln16}<1$$

Because $x\ln16$ will always be greater than 1, the reciprocal of that will always be zero for $x>1$. By this, we can conclude that the second curve grows at a rate smaller than the first one for every value of x when $x>1$. Because we know the values of the first equation at $x=1$, is 1 while the other one is 0, we can say that these graphs **do not intersect**. So, there are no roots.

Comment: "knowing that $x>0$": no.

Comment: We know that $x > 0$ because in x is negative, the left side of the equation $x = 16^x$ will be negative while the right side will always be positive (Edit: you're right.)

Comment: Hmm thanks. Interesting

Answer (score 0):

If one graphs both sides of this equation one gets that the real number, $x$, is about -0.3642.  Here is a Desmos graph showing this:  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lvztuajkgk

This equation does not have an elementary solution (i.e. a solution that is able to be expressed in terms of polynomials, power functions, exponential functions, and logs).

Comment: That's an interesting graph. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using $x=16^x$

$x^{\frac{1}{x}}=16$

The point ($e$, ~1.4) is the "vertex" if you will, so the function will never exceed $e^{\frac{1}{e}}$ thus $x=16^x$ is undefined

Comment: Care to read the other answers.

Comment: Ok thanks man. Grateful